# Приложение с механизмом Web Application Firewall

Tags: база-данных, веб-программирование, uml, firewall

Всем доброго времени суток, нужно написать приложение для защиты Web приложений.
Приложение должно:

- 1) Блокировать:
- SQL Injection — sql инъекции;
- Remote Code Execution (RCE) — удаленное выполнение кода;
- Cross Site Scripting (XSS) — межсайтовый скриптинг;
- Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF) — межстайтовую подделку запросов;
- 2) Выявлять бот-активность
- 3) Не зависеть от платформы веб-приложения

Уже разобрался в методе анализа данных и тд.
**Теперь вопрос:**

- 1) нужна помощь в создании структуры программы (было бы совсем
  здорово если представлено в виде UML диаграмм)
- 2) нужна помощь в    проектировании базы данных, разумеется
  проектировать не надо, просто    в общем виде какие таблицы должна
  содержать база. Саму структуру.

Comment: Что-то я как-то не понял, зачем здесь база данных вообще. Кроме того, я сильно сомневаюсь в реальности создания такого проекта вообще (в частности, я совершенно не представляю, как защищаться от RCE кроме как исправлением найденных уязвимостей непосредственно в веб-приложении)

Comment: используя обратный прокси nginx для получения запроса сначала на сервере, а затем отфильтровывая их на моем back end-сервере, где находится материал. Затем добавить собственные функции с моего обратного прокси-сервера. Так же можно добавить кучу правил и тд . Это как вариант реализации.

Comment: Да и как это не возможно создать, если существует много Web Application Firewall и бесплатные и платные версии.

Comment: Я уверен, что все существующие Firewall не защитили бы от кривой png-аватарки с исполняемым кодом внутри неё :) (Будет очень круто, если я не прав)

Comment: Я знаю, тем не мене мне нужно реализовать данное приложение.

Comment: Для Stack Overflow вопрос всё равно слишком общий. Это *ваше* приложение, это *вам* виднее, какую «кучу правил» реализовывать, *вам* решать, что как хранить и *вам* выбирать структуру под ваши конкретные задачи (которые сейчас описаны вопросе уж слишком расплывчато)